# Unit test failing for mysql driver with java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to write Unit tests for the following methods of RDSDao class like unassignTask for starters:

```
public class RDSDao {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(RDSDao.class);

    /**
     * Parameters for SQL DB Connection
     */
    private final Connection connection;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    private ResultSet resultSet;
    private Map<String, String> constants;

    @Inject
    public RDSDao(SecretsManager secretsManager) throws SQLException {
        String stage = System.getenv("stage");
        constants = StarkConstants.PROD_STAGE.equals(stage) ? StarkConstants.prod
                : StarkConstants.beta;
        this.connection = createMysqlConnection(secretsManager);
    }

    /**
     * Create RDS mysql connection
     *
     * @param secretsManager
     *
     * @return Connection
     *
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public Connection createMysqlConnection(SecretsManager secretsManager) throws SQLException {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Initializing mysql connection");
            System.out.println("Inside createMysqlConnection");
            JsonObject secretsObject = secretsManager.getSecret();
            System.out.println("Secrets object:"+secretsObject);

            LOGGER.info("Rds database key name to be fetched from secrets : {}", constants.get(StarkConstants.RDS_DB_KEY));

            String rdsUrl = String.format(StarkConstants.JDBC_URL,
                    secretsObject.get(StarkConstants.HOST_KEY).getAsString(),
                    secretsObject.get(StarkConstants.PORT_KEY).getAsInt(),
                    secretsObject.get(constants.get(StarkConstants.RDS_DB_KEY)).getAsString());
            System.out.println("RDS url:"+rdsUrl);

            LOGGER.info("RDS URL for getting connection : {}, User key to be fetched from secrets: {}",
                    rdsUrl, constants.get(StarkConstants.USER_KEY));

            return DriverManager.getConnection(rdsUrl,
                    secretsObject.get(constants.get(StarkConstants.USER_KEY)).getAsString(),
                    secretsObject.get(StarkConstants.PASSWORD_KEY).getAsString());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("SQL error executing createMysqlConnection : {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the sbr_status basis issue_id in RDS table issues
     *
     * @param simId
     *
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void unassignTask(String simId) throws SQLException {

        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQLConstants.UNASSIGN_TASK_QUERY);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, simId);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            LOGGER.info("Updated RDS table issues for sim ID : {}", simId);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getStackTrace());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get list of issues that are manually assigned and elapsed 20 mins after assignment.
     *
     * @param thresholdTime
     *
     * @return List
     *
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public List<String> getManualAssignedElapsedSims(String thresholdTime)
            throws SQLException {

        try {
            List<String> issueList = new ArrayList<>();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQLConstants.MANUAL_ASSIGNED_SIMS_TIME_ELAPSED_QUERY);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, thresholdTime);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                LOGGER.info("Issue ID : {}, Assigned Timestamp : {}",
                        resultSet.getString(StarkConstants.ISSUE_ID),
                        resultSet.getString(StarkConstants.ASSIGNED_TIMESTAMP));
                issueList.add(resultSet.getString(StarkConstants.ISSUE_ID));
            }
            LOGGER.info("Number of issues manually assigned that elapsed 20 minutes : {}",
                    issueList.size());
            return issueList;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getStackTrace());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the UT I have written:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class RDSDaoTest {

    @Mock
    PreparedStatement mockPreparedStatement;
    @Mock
    ResultSet mockResultSet;
    @Mock
    SecretsManager secretsManager;

    @Mock
    Connection mockConnection;
    RDSDao rdsDao;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws SQLException {

        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        try (MockedStatic<DriverManager> driverManager = Mockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class)) {
            when(secretsManager.getSecret()).thenReturn(getMockSecretsObject());
            driverManager.when(() -> DriverManager.getConnection(any(String.class),
                            eq("mockUser"), eq("mockPassword"))).
                    thenReturn(mockConnection);
        }
        rdsDao = new RDSDao(secretsManager);
       }

    @Test
    public void testUnassignTask_Success() throws SQLException {
        when(mockConnection.prepareStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(mockPreparedStatement);

        rdsDao.unassignTask("TestSim");

        verify(mockPreparedStatement).setString(1, "TestSim");
        verify(mockPreparedStatement).executeUpdate();
    }

    private JsonObject getMockSecretsObject() {
        JsonObject secretsObject = new JsonObject();
        secretsObject.addProperty(StarkConstants.HOST_KEY, "mockHost");
        secretsObject.addProperty(StarkConstants.PORT_KEY, 1234);
        secretsObject.addProperty("database", "mockRdsDbKey");
        secretsObject.addProperty("user", "mockUser");
        secretsObject.addProperty(StarkConstants.PASSWORD_KEY, "mockPassword");
        System.out.println("Mock secrets object:"+secretsObject);

        return secretsObject;
    }
}
```

But i keep getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
```

What am i doing wrong? How to fix this?
NOTE: Reason I did not use @InjectMocks for RDSDao is it was unable to mock the param SecretsManager properly.

Comment: This is fixed:
```
        try (MockedStatic<DriverManager> driverManager = Mockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
             AutoCloseable mocks = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)) {

            when(secretsManager.getSecret()).thenReturn(getMockSecretsObject());
            driverManager.when(() -> DriverManager.getConnection(any(String.class),
                            eq("mockUser"), eq("mockPassword"))).
                    thenReturn(mockConnection);
            rdsDao = new RDSDao(secretsManager);
        }
```